# Trying for print output to show as Characters not range places

Tags: python

> Create a program that determines the number of occurrences of each letter in the quote "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data.", and output a list with each letter and its frequency.

```
sentence="You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
sentence.lower()
Alpha=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]

for i in range(0,26):
    print((i),":",sentence.count(Alpha[i]))
```

This is the code I have curently wrien, expected output was

```
a: 10
b: 2 
etc.
```

what have I missed to achive this output instead of

```
0: 10
1: 2 
etc.
```

Comment: Change `(i)` to `Alpha[i]`.

Comment: `sentence.lower()` should be `sentence = sentence.lower()`. Strings are immutable, it can't modify it in place.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help, I was tryong to use () brackets in the statment.

Comment: One hint if you need the ASCII alphabet again in a new script: If you import `string` you can simply use `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence="You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
sentence = sentence.lower()
Alpha=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]

# you can enumerate Alpha and range in parallel using zip() or Access Alpha[i] directly
for a, i in zip(Alpha, range(0,26)):
    print((a),":",sentence.count(Alpha[i]))
```

Comment: Why not `count(a)`? And why use `zip()` when you can use `enumerate()`?

Comment: I didnt think about it as I wanted to keep the changes minimal. But I agree, enumerate is more elegant. haha, and the last piece I wrote before was a zip statement, maybe it stuck somewhere in my mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another slight variation to what has already been posted is

```py
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase as alpha

sentence = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."

counted = Counter(sentence.lower())
for letter in alpha:
    print(f"{letter}: {counted[letter]}")
```

This uses the [Counter class from the collections library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the letters in the sentence.

This will give the output

```
a: 10
b: 1
c: 2
d: 2
e: 2
f: 2
g: 0
...
```